# Get transformation of mesh/object during animation

Tags: java, libgdx

I have 3 cubes attached to an armature. When animating, is it possible to get the transformation of a specific cube?

The 2 top cubes wave up and down. What I'm trying to do is place the red cube on the left white cube while animating, making it look like the red cube is animated.

```
private void doneLoading() {
    Model model = assets.get("data/cubes.g3db", Model.class);
    Model model2 = assets.get("data/colored.g3db", Model.class);

    cubes = new ModelInstance(model);
    con = new AnimationController(cubes);
    con.setAnimation(cubes.animations.get(0).id, -1);

    red = new ModelInstance(model2, "Red");

    instances.add(cubes);
    instances.add(red);
}

//in render function
if(!loading){
    //Tried, but it's not changing during animation
    //Node left = cubes.getNode("Cubel");
    //Matrix4 mat = left.globalTransform; 
    //System.out.println(mat.toString()); 
            
    //This worked but the red cube is on the bone's position, not on the white cube's.
    Matrix4 mat = con.current.animation.nodeAnimations.get(0).node.globalTransform;     
    red.transform.set(mat);

    con.update(delta);
    loading = false;
}
```

yellow - represents the armature or the bones

green - the movement during animation
[image]